# Weaker sufficient conditions to reflect monos and epis than faithfulness?

Tags: category-theory

I am looking for a weaker condition than faithfulness to test when a functor might reflect both monomorphisms and epimorphisms. It seems that faithfulness is somewhat overkill for this; I don't really want to go through and verify definitively when a functor actually reflects both, but an easier set of properties of a functor to go over to get an idea would be helpful. For some context, I am interested in arbitrary functors into $\Delta_a$, the augmented simplex category, but other settings interest me as well. I have tried hunting around online, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Is there some example of a non-faithful functor reflecting monos and epis that you'd like to generalize?

Comment: @EricWofsey In particular, the functor $FinSet \rightarrow FinSet/\cong$ into the quotient by isomorphism (or the corresponding case for finite ordered sets). This is certainly not faithful, but does reflect epis and monos.

Comment: What do you mean by "the quotient by isomorphism"?  What are the morphisms in that quotient?

Comment: @EricWofsey Morphisms are functions between finite cardinals.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, that functor is not canonical (to define it, you have to choose an ordering on every finite set) and is faithful...

Comment: Oh, I see now. Is it the case, then, that faithfulness is necessary and sufficient for a functor to reflect monos and epis?

Comment: No, for instance, take the category with two objects and two parallel arrows between them.  Every map in that category is monic and epic so any functor from this category reflects them, but not every functor is faithful.

Comment: Oh, because we could just map everything onto a single arrow. That makes sense. I have actually realized now that I am in fact needing conditions for a functor to PRESERVE both epis and monos, but I am now independently curious also as to how we might characterize functors that reflect both. I appreciate your comments and helpful attitude.